# TinyMCE inserting child with valid_children in table not working

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tinymce, mustache

we use TinyMCE in combination with JMustache. Users can insert mustache variables into the text from TinyMCE to create a template.
We now have a problem with loops in combination with tables. The loop must start before a `<tr>`  and stop after the `</tr>` so that one iteration equals one row. TinyMCE uses tbody in addition. So the HTML would have to look like this:

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 32px;" border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 24.9891%;">
        <col style="width: 24.9891%;">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="height: 16px;">Name</td>
        <td style="height: 16px;">Birthday</td>
    </tr>
    <p>{{#PERSONS}}</p>
    <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="height: 16px;">
            <p><br>{{NAME}}</p>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 16px;">
            <p>{{BIRTHDAY}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <p>{{/PERSONS}}</p>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If we put this in TinyMCE, the variable will detect invalid HTML and the loop start/end will be moved out of tbody.
According to the documentation, the solution to our problem would be to use `valid_childen`. We enclosed the variables in a `<p>` tag and added `valid_children: "+tbody[p]"` to the TinyMCE configuration.
Unfortunately it does nothing and the paragraph is moved away again.

Here is an example for our TinyMCE configuration:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen", 
        "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media", 
        "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks", 
    ],
    toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    valid_children: "+tbody[p]"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

I have created an example here where you can try it out: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/V5iaab
The HTML code from above can be inserted via Tools -> Source code.

Also tried `valid_children: "*[*]"` but same problem.

This is my first post, I hope you can understand the problem.

Maybe it's a bug or someone has an idea?